# subset data based on value in a column and keep only those with existing values in two other columns

Tags: r

I tried to find a related answer for this but was unsuccessful. I'm trying to subset a dataframe with unique values in a row, but only those with existing values in two other columns.

Here's a reprex:

```
 df <- data.frame(
      id = c(10000, 10000, 10002, 10005, 10005, 10002, 10000, 10005, 10002, 10000),
      name = c("jane", NA, NA, "jeff", NA, "tom", NA, NA, NA, NA),
      date = c(NA, 1/1/2010, 4/4/2012, NA, 3/3/2011, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))

df_desired <- data.frame(
    id = c(10000, 10002, 10005),
    name = c("jane", "tom", "jeff"),
    date = c(1/1/2010, 4/4/2012, 3/3/2011))
```

in other words, I need to condense the rows for each name to match a date, while subsetting for unique ids.

Comment: Try `library(dplyr);df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(across(everything(),  ~.x[complete.cases(.x)][1]), .groups = 'drop')`

Comment: I think this will work! I will try this on the larger dataset and get back to you.

Comment: hi @akrun, could you tell me how this works:

summarise(across(everything(),  ~.x[complete.cases(.x)][1]), .groups

how can I specify to keep complete cases of those two columns (i.e. if other columns have NAs, keep that row)